# How to get default system style on C# progressbar

Tags: c#

In Windows Vista & 7 progressbars are green and have a glassy finish.  But the one served up by Visual Studio 2010 has the system default of blue highlight (which appears flat and looks a bit Windows 98).

How do I get that glassy green look (or whatever the user's theme default is)?

(Using C# v4.0 if that makes a difference)

[image: Dull flat blue progress bar]

**EDIT:**  Ok - just noticed how square the buttons look on this and other dialogs' controls - I think somehow the entire app is being styled pre win XP?  Can someone tell me how to set the style correctly for the whole app (i.e. to match the current OS)?

Comment: This should work automatically. Is the rest of your application also looking Win98 like?

Comment: @Daniel Hilgarth - window borders, buttons etc all styled like a vista/7.  But even if I create a new solution/project (Windows Forms) the properties are set to "Highlight"

Comment: @Jim Mischel - Windows Forms (i'm fairly certain, it's an Automation Addin for Excel)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this line in your `Program.cs` :

```
static void Main()
{
    Application.EnableVisualStyles();
```

Comment: Brilliant thanks Cicada (and everyone else).   The app is a Automation Addin so no Main() method but I just stuck this in the constructor of my class that implements Extensibility.IDTExtensibility2 - hey presto all working